# how to get particular value to create an array from a nested object

Tags: javascript

I have this below object structure which is having 3 records as a sample now. But We will be having more than 20 records.

```
{
    "data": [{
            "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
            "values": {
                "identifier": "access8770009prd",
                "shortdescription": "<p>Hybrid Dual Injection Cover and a Tempered Glass.<\/p>",
                "displayname": "Protection Essentials Bundle - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) 822445132623"
            }
        },
        {
            "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
            "values": {
                "identifier": "access8530068prd",
                "shortdescription": "String.class",
                "displayname": "JBL UA Flex Headphones (Gray) - 050036342735"
            }
        }, {
            "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
            "values": {
                "identifier": "access8630012prd",
                "shortdescription": "<p>This slim case has everything you want - style and protection.<\/p>",
                "displayname": "Otterbox Symmetry Series Case - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) - 660543444121"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

From the above object, I need to get this below array.

```
identifierList = [ 'access8770009prd', 'access8530068prd', 'access8630012prd' ]
```

as a single dimensional array. Can anyone please provide an efficient approach.

Comment: That's not [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) ...

Comment: Which one you are mentioning?

Comment: The same as you mention as "_JSON object_". From the [tag-Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info): "_JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a textual data interchange format and language-independent. Use this tag when this text format is involved. DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR NATIVE JAVASCRIPT OBJECTS OR JAVASCRIPT OBJECT LITERALS._"

Comment: Your `identifierList` in your desired output is not an array but an object instead. I take it this should've been `['access8770009prd', 'access8530068prd', 'access8630012prd']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **map()** with array destructuring to get that array of `identifier`.

```js
var data = [{
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8770009prd",
      "shortdescription": "<p>Hybrid Dual Injection Cover and a Tempered Glass.<\/p>",
      "displayname": "Protection Essentials Bundle - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) 822445132623"
    }
  },
  {
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8530068prd",
      "shortdescription": "String.class",
      "displayname": "JBL UA Flex Headphones (Gray) - 050036342735"
    }
  }, {
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8630012prd",
      "shortdescription": "<p>This slim case has everything you want - style and protection.<\/p>",
      "displayname": "Otterbox Symmetry Series Case - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) - 660543444121"
    }
  }
];
var identifierList = data.map(({values}) => values.identifier);
console.log(identifierList);
```

**USING forEach()**

```js
var data = [{
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8770009prd",
      "shortdescription": "<p>Hybrid Dual Injection Cover and a Tempered Glass.<\/p>",
      "displayname": "Protection Essentials Bundle - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) 822445132623"
    }
  },
  {
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8530068prd",
      "shortdescription": "String.class",
      "displayname": "JBL UA Flex Headphones (Gray) - 050036342735"
    }
  }, {
    "datatype": "AccessoryProduct",
    "values": {
      "identifier": "access8630012prd",
      "shortdescription": "<p>This slim case has everything you want - style and protection.<\/p>",
      "displayname": "Otterbox Symmetry Series Case - Samsung Galaxy S9 (Clear) - 660543444121"
    }
  }
];
var identifierList = [];
data.forEach(({values}) => identifierList.push(values.identifier));
console.log(identifierList);
```

Comment: @Shanmugam glad to help

Answer (score 1):

if `a` is the json you have you can do the follwing

```
identifierList = a.data.map(x => x.values.identifier)
```

Comment: OK fine. I ll try it and let u know